# Fixing huge performance degradation after upgrading to Postgres 12 if column expressions are used

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, query-optimization

Query returns no rows but its execution time in Postgres 12 depends on the column expression.

Query with  column expression

```
coalesce( (select sum(taitmata) 
 from rid join dok using (dokumnr)
where toode=toode.toode and doktyyp='T' 
and not dok.taidetud and dok.kinnitatud and 
taitmata is not null),0)
```

takes huge amount of time:

```
explain analyze select 
    coalesce( (select sum(taitmata) from rid join dok using (dokumnr)
    where toode=toode.toode and doktyyp='T' and not dok.taidetud and dok.kinnitatud and 
    taitmata is not null),0) 
    from toode 
        where toode.ribakood='testmiin'::text
           or toode.nimetus ilike '%'||'testmiin'||'%'            or toode.toode ilike '%'||'testmiin'||'%'           
      or toode.markused ilike '%'||'testmiin'||'%'
           or to_tsvector('english',toode.nimetus) @@ plainto_tsquery('testmiin') 
             or to_tsvector('english',toode.engnimetus) @@  plainto_tsquery('testmiin')  


"Gather  (cost=1000.00..505930.82 rows=153 width=32) (actual time=785.410..785.478 rows=0 loops=1)"
"  Workers Planned: 1"
"  Workers Launched: 1"
"  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on toode  (cost=0.00..10015.31 rows=90 width=21) (actual time=608.346..608.346 rows=0 loops=2)"
"        Filter: (((ribakood)::text = 'testmiin'::text) OR (nimetus ~~* '%testmiin%'::text) OR (toode ~~* '%testmiin%'::text) OR (markused ~~* '%testmiin%'::text) OR (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, (nimetus)::text) @@ plainto_tsquery('testmiin'::text)) OR (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, (engnimetus)::text) @@ plainto_tsquery('testmiin'::text)))"
"        Rows Removed by Filter: 7202"
"  SubPlan 1"
"    ->  Aggregate  (cost=3234.63..3234.64 rows=1 width=32) (never executed)"
"          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=11.26..3234.52 rows=43 width=3) (never executed)"
"                ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on rid  (cost=10.84..1191.72 rows=270 width=7) (never executed)"
"                      Recheck Cond: (toode = toode.toode)"
"                      Filter: (taitmata IS NOT NULL)"
"                      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on rid_toode_pattern_idx  (cost=0.00..10.77 rows=312 width=0) (never executed)"
"                            Index Cond: (toode = toode.toode)"
"                ->  Index Scan using dok_pkey on dok  (cost=0.42..7.57 rows=1 width=4) (never executed)"
"                      Index Cond: (dokumnr = rid.dokumnr)"
"                      Filter: ((NOT taidetud) AND kinnitatud AND (doktyyp = 'T'::bpchar))"
"Planning Time: 4.907 ms"
"JIT:"
"  Functions: 24"
"  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true"
"  Timing: Generation 5.168 ms, Inlining 157.637 ms, Optimization 474.786 ms, Emission 304.165 ms, Total 941.756 ms"
"Execution Time: 830.674 ms"
```

Same query with simple column expression

1

run many times faster:

```
explain analyze select 1
from toode 
    where toode.ribakood='testmiin'::text
       or toode.nimetus ilike '%'||'testmiin'||'%'            
       or toode.toode ilike '%'||'testmiin'||'%'            
       or toode.markused ilike '%'||'testmiin'||'%'            or to_tsvector('english',toode.nimetus) @@ plainto_tsquery('testmiin') 
         or to_tsvector('english',toode.engnimetus) @@
         plainto_tsquery('testmiin')  



"Gather  (cost=1000.00..11030.61 rows=153 width=4) (actual time=178.712..180.697 rows=0 loops=1)"
"  Workers Planned: 1"
"  Workers Launched: 1"
"  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on toode  (cost=0.00..10015.31 rows=90 width=4) (actual time=160.552..160.552 rows=0 loops=2)"
"        Filter: (((ribakood)::text = 'testmiin'::text) OR (nimetus ~~* '%testmiin%'::text) OR (toode ~~* '%testmiin%'::text) OR (markused ~~* '%testmiin%'::text) OR (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, (nimetus)::text) @@ plainto_tsquery('testmiin'::text)) OR (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, (engnimetus)::text) @@ plainto_tsquery('testmiin'::text)))"
"        Rows Removed by Filter: 7202"
"Planning Time: 4.131 ms"
"Execution Time: 180.727 ms"
```

If there are more column expressions, perfomance difference is bigger.
rid  table used in column expression contains 1.8 million of rows.
Performance degradation probably occured if upgraded from Postgres 9.1 to Postgres 12

Since no data is returned query perfomance should be same.
How to fix it ?

Comment: Please post the execution plan without mangling and added line breaks.

Comment: I updated question. `SET jit to off` recommended by Pavel Stehule in pgsql-general list fixes the issue. If there are more column expressions containing select statements with join, perfomance loss is bigger.

Comment: Do you *really* need the OR-list with three `ILIKE '%aaa%` , plus a text - search? I would not even try to optimise this...

Comment: Yes. This is search box in e-shop. If some word is entered, it should searched in product description, product name and product properties columns. It is like google search over diferent columns in product table.

Comment: If you want efficient search, you best restrict the way in which people can search. Three letter substrings are too short.

Comment: Sampe code in question does NOT contain 3-letter search term. It contains `testmiin` as search term. Currently whole toode table is probably always scanned. Maybe it is reasonable to create composite fts index on toode fields so that only FTS index or part of toode is scanned